# How to read from Stream that's written by async method

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function to download file from FTP with following signature:

```
BeginDownloadFile(string path, Stream ouputStream);
```

This function downloads file asynchronously and stores data in *outputStream*.

In another method, I need to read available bytes on *ouputStream* stream instantly.

e.g. if `BeginDownloadFile` stored 500 bytes to `ouputStream` i need to read it to buffer (in another method) and do some logic with these bytes and so on.

So theoretically when `BeginDownloadFile` will write last portion of bytes into `outputStream` my method should also read the last portion.

I can't wait untill `BeginDownloadFile` will download all file. 
I'm using .net 4.

thanks for help

Comment: We need more information on this. How is that async process? Threads?

Comment: Write a class inheriting from `Stream`. That way, you can control every bytes read or written,

Comment: @ Adrian Carneiro - i'm using commericial lib to work with FTP so I don't know internals of BeginDownloadFile clause

Comment: @I4V nice idea - I haven't thinked about it. It can help to solve this problem. Thanks